# URL mapping in Django (Tutorial)

Tags: python, django

I started with Django using the tutorial with the polls (as seen on the PyCharm site https://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/help/creating-and-running-your-first-django-project.html). I use Python 3.5.1, Django 1.9.4 and Pycharm 5.0.4, the tutorial is from December 2015 and asks for at least Python 3.4.1. and Django 1.8.0 or higher.

The problem is, I guess, in the file urls.py (which is based in the polls-app folder). The content is:

```
from django.conf.urls import include, url
from django.contrib import admin
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^polls/', include('polls.urls')), #this line added
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
]
```

and the error message I receive, when visiting http://127.0.0.1:8000/polls/1

```
Using the URLconf defined in mysite.urls, Django tried these URL
> patterns, in this order: 
> 1. ^polls/ ^$ [name='index']
> 2. ^admin/
> The current URL, polls/1, didn't match any of these.
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The PyCharm tutorial you are following is incomplete. It only gives one url to add to `polls/urls.py`.

```
url(r'^$', views.index, name='index'),
```

This will handle `/polls/`. The tutorial does not give instructions how to handle other urls like `/polls/1/`.

You would be better to use the [official Django tutorial](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/intro/tutorial01/), which also creates a polls app. It is kept up to date with each new Django release. You might be able to jump to [this section](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/intro/tutorial03/#writing-more-views) and update the `polls/urls.py` by adding these patterns:

```
# ex: /polls/5/
url(r'^(?P<question_id>[0-9]+)/$', views.detail, name='detail'),
# ex: /polls/5/results/
url(r'^(?P<question_id>[0-9]+)/results/$', views.results, name='results'),
# ex: /polls/5/vote/
url(r'^(?P<question_id>[0-9]+)/vote/$', views.vote, name='vote'),
```

Answer (score 0):

In my configuration there where two urls.py files and I was editing the wrong one:

```
\mysite
    urls.py
    \mysite
        urls.py <--- modify this one
```

After editing the deeper as shown above, it works!